# If $A \times B = B \times A$, what can we conclude about the sets and $A$ and $B$? Justify your answer

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A \times B = B \times A$, what can we conclude about the sets and $A$ and $B$? Justify your
answer

I'm not sure how to properly justify it but the only possible way would be if $A = B$ right?

For example if the set was $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B = \{1,2,3\}$ then $A \times B = B \times A$ equaling

$\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)\}$

Also

Q) $|A \times B| = |A|$, what can we conclude about the sets A and B? Justify your answer.

Wouldn't this only be possible if $B = \emptyset$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one of the sets is empty then $A \times B=B \times A$ and  nothing can be said about eh other set. If both sets are non-empty then $A=B$. To prove this consider the map $p$ defined by $p(x,y)=x$. Apply $p$ to the equation $A \times B=B \times A$ and you will get $A=B$. Q): if $A$ is empty nothing can be said about $B$. Otherwise $B$ must have exactly one element unless $A$ and $B$ are infinite sets.

Comment: I think it could be worth mentioning that the last sentence works only if $A$ is finite.

Comment: @GuidoA. Thanks. Corrected.